# Is Married at First Sight a real scientific experiment?

Tags: married-at-first-sight

During the Australian TV show *[Married at First Sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Married_at_First_Sight_(Australian_TV_series)),* they’re very insistent on referring to it as an experiment while on the show, and apparently some of the show’s staff have referred to it as a documentary.

What I want to know is if this is true. Has anyone involved in the making of the show (in any of its international variations, not just Australian) written any scientific papers on it? It seems like it would likely violate rules on experimental ethics.

Comment: Well you could argue that is a social experiment and it's a TV experiment at the same time, because it's about seeing how this works out (narrative), but also how the audience takes said narrative, but most reality shows are "scripted" and therfore they aren't exactly the same as a documentary even though they may filmed in a Documentary style. I have read (not sure accurate this is) that they go through a crazy process to get what they want from extreme vetting, to major editing, to keeping couples separated at certain times https://www.who.com.au/married-at-first-sight-scripted-faked

Comment: I'm sure they use 'experiment' and 'documentary' to lend some gravitas to what is fundamentally just reality tv.